# How to fix fog lights not working, on Hyundai Tucson 2013 GLS 4DR?

Tags: electrical, battery, car, hyundai, headlight

My fog lights are not working, and I don't remember them ever working. I attempted a number of things, but nothing worked.

The voltage of the lights when switched on is ~4.0V. Since other battery powered components are working, I suspected this to be a fuse issue. But there is no fuse mentioned in the [manual](https://manual-directory.com/manual/2013-hyundai-tucson-owners-manual/) for the front fog lights!

I thought there there must be a wiring harness issue, but then realized that both fog lights (which have different connections) are off.

Can someone help me? I have an upcoming long highway trip. :(

Comment: How exactly did you measure the 4 volts?

Comment: What is a "TC highway"? Why do you need lights that you have never used? If there are measurable volts at the lamps it can't be a fuse issue.

Comment: Does the warning light on the dashboard described on page 1-7 come on?

Comment: Did you have the headlights on when you tried to turn the fog lights on?

Comment: Have you checked if the bulbs are blown?

Comment: Thabks all for reply. 1) multimeter 2) trans-canada highway 3) No 4) Yes 5) I just installed new bulbs.

Comment: @WeatherVane I relocated cause of covid. 
ok, what steps can I take to diagnose further?

Comment: I was expecting a little more information on how you measured the 4 volts.  Where exactly did you put the multimeter probes?  Was the bulb in the holder at the time?  Was the 4v present only when the lamp was  Switched on?